# Jmeter response times - TTFB or TTLB?

Tags: jmeter

Are these response times from JMeter TTFB or TTLB?

Comment: Perhaps you could provide us with some more information on which response times you are referring to.

Comment: Response times from a SOAP request and HTTP request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Response time is "time to last byte"

http://jmeter.512774.n5.nabble.com/JMeter-results-td516516.html

Answer (score 4):

If you use Jmeter **View Results Tree** CSV output, then you have following time values:

1. Elapsed: TTLB - time to last byte
2. Latency: TTFB - time to first byte
3. Connect: time to connect to server, includes SSL Handling

All times are in msec.
[JMeter Manual Glossary](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html)