# How to calculate response time from Google Chrome Dev. Tools

Tags: performance, google-chrome, jmeter, google-chrome-devtools, performance-testing

I am trying to calculate response time of different requests from Google Chrome Browser Developer Tools. It provides various time values against each request. But not sure which one is the response time (as it is calculated by JMeter performance testing tool). To be more precise I want value of TTLB (Time to Last Byte) instead of TTFB (Time to First Byte).

Below is a sample screenshot showing various values for one of request that are provided by Chrome Dev Tools.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Surely: **TTLB = TTFB + 'Content Download' time**?

The [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network) describes 'Content Download' as:

> Time spent receiving the response data

So it seems to make perfect sense that this is the difference between the arrival of the first and last byte.

As for JMeter, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957991/jmeter-response-times-ttfb-or-ttlb):

> Response time is "time to last byte"

which again seems to make sense.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. This surely makes sense. However, I am amazed as I was not able to find any online resources pointing to calculation of TTLB. Thanks again.